# Engineers are coding behind thin clients

Tags: company-policy

This is a policy that bothers me a lot. The company, for some kind of security reasons, requires us to edit&build codes behind a thin client computer which has no Internet access and can only access Build server and Version control server. We cannot view our code on fat client. The topology is something look like this:

```
Five Build servers          <--- Two Thin clients <-|--- Many Fat clients
One Version Control server       (isolated subnet)  |
```

For an engineer, we always need to find some information online or to read documents on our personal computer(fat client). As a result, we have to constantly switch between thin client and fat client **everyday**.

For me, I have to use remote desktop to connect to thin client, and then use Putty inside thin client to connect to servers to edit&build codes. After build process complete, I have to get the image file back to fat client and upload to my embedded system.

I believe it has great impacts on our performances but the company has no will to change it. I don't think I could do anything about it neither since I work in this company for only a few months.

The question is, is there any good reason to have engineers write their codes behind a thin client without Internet access? if not, should I try to convince my colleagues and superior to get rid of thin client? I tend to find information to prove this is bad idea.

Comment: You say in your first paragraph that the company does it for security reasons. Also, you say that you nonetheless have internet access through your own fat client (workstation) provided by the company. So is there really a problem here other than the inconvenience of switching between clients as you say?

Comment: It's true that I cannot figure out any other problem other than the inconvenience of switching between clients. Though we saved our source code behind thin client, we still write confidential documents in fat clients and never save these documents inside thin client.

Comment: What do you mean by behind? its not clear what the problem is you are trying to solve

Comment: Let's say I have to use remote desktop to connect to thin client, and then use Putty inside thin client to connect to servers. I will edit my question to clarify this. :)

Comment: You know, I worked at a place that does this.  Windows 7 machines, have to remote to a Windows XP computer so it has access to... IE6.

However, your setup also doesn't make much sense.  So your thin client connection is strictly intranet only?  Your thin client cannot access internet?  But then you're using a fat client to remote to the thin client... and your fat client has internet?

Comment: Also, the policy smells like "Management is too stupid to understand why we have to do this, so we'll just make something up."  It is entirely possible that the thin client can do something your fat client outright cannot do.  The situation I described required IE6 because it is a massive ActiveX IE6 system that doesn't work with anything else, and it has 15 years of Pharmaceutical R&D data on it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the case here, if I know it can do something that fat client cannot do, I won't complain it. :s

Comment: You could certainly try convincing the management, but you need solid data to back up your claim. "I don't want to work in this manner because it sucks" won't convince anyone to change. Supporting evidence, especially numerical evidence, will make your case stronger. However, be aware that if your management is okay with you working "inefficiently", you won't have much of a choice in the matter. Bluntly speaking, they pay you to do a job that they want done, not necessarily for you to work "efficiently". I know it sucks, but such is the reality.

Comment: @Nelson, there are legitimate reasons for this setup (see Keshlam's answer), so jumping to the conclusion that management is incompetent, when very little information is provided by the OP, is unwarranted.

Comment: Well, I didn't say management is flat out incompetent.  I'm saying management probably cannot grasp the full implication of the complexity of the setup and was simply told "it is for security".  I'm not certain how the step of having fat clients login to a thin client adds to security in a way that offsets the productivity loss, but I just don't know enough about the decision process anyways.  Unless all you have are thin clients, having fat clients login to thin clients seems redundant.  Why not just secure the fat clients instead?

Comment: @Masked Man Good point, I think I'll be okay too if they're okay with me working inefficiently. Still I hope I can find more advantage/disadvantage about this thin client setup to back me up. I don't really familiar with business management.

Comment: This policy is clearly pathological. But, in your place, I would simply find a way to automatize the ssh and also the remote desktop (it _is_ possible, although not really simple). Ssh automating is nearly trivial, for rdesktop automatizing use google. From this point, you have a technical and not job question, which I suggest to re-ask on some of the technical SE sites (stackoverflow, softwarerecs, etc).

Comment: Is management satisfied with your level of production? If they're asking for for more efficiency, but you're hindered by this setup, you may have a case. Otherwise, it seems they're willing to sacrifice your feelings of productivity to gain the level of security they feel this accomplishes.

Comment: The OP is asking if he should apply a particular solution. There are ways to go about having influence in the workplace, so I don't see why this is off topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are legitimate reasons for isolating the development lab from the public networks, ranging from security (not just spying/leakage but malware/ransomware hazards) to provable "clean room" development. Which of those reasons applies to your company I can't guess.

One of our customers has a dev lab with ***no*** connection to outside. Employees can't even carry a disk or thumb drive into or out of the building without explicit permission; personal laptops must be checked at the door; wifi only available in the lobby or customer-facng conference room. Compared to that, you really have nothing to complain about.

(We have a similar-but-different isolation regime we use when supporting customers whose problems can only be diagnosed with real, and highly sensitive, data. When considering serious computer security, paranoia is insufficient.)

As you said, you are on the way out, which make the whole question moot. Otherwise I'd tell you to ask internally to find out who set this policy, ask them what specific risks it addresses, and only then consider whether there is a better way to address those specific concerns.

Comment: Good answer, I know at least one financial institution that has security this tight. I also know a company who practically locks there devs down for a totally different reason, too much abuse of  network and internet.

Comment: Thanks for advice, "clean room" development seems to be most probable in this case. Though I haven't ask about actual security reasons yet, I still have my doubt since the company only secured the source code.

Comment: There are regulatory/legal reasons why you can't see production as well . For instance in the medical community, patient records are legally only allowed to be seen by people directly participating in the treatment of that patient which most assuredly does not include developers.